# Failed to make glossy date syrup

Tags: syrup, puree, date-fruit

I tried to make date syrup but ended up with something more like date puree. I attempted to boil the mixture for a longer period of time, but it didn't help. I also tried to strain it through a sieve, but everything still passed through to the bowl. What should I do?

Comment: what process did you follow to make date syrup?

Comment: @Esther- Just boiling dates with water, then straining the mixture to separate the pits and skins. For 700 gr dates, I added 1500 ml water.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you are after correctly, (I may not - I have not made *date* syrup) a jelly bag or other dense fabric/felt filter is far more likely to remove the fine solid material than a sieve. A jelly bag comes immediately to mind as its common use is to remove fine solids from hot syrupy food products, leaving only clear liquids.

We also used them to filter maple syrup on a home-production scale (not commonly used commercially, as far as I know.)

Some are more of a fine mesh and would be less likely to remove date pulp. Unfortunately search results for felt ones are now polluted with craft junk for sale.

Comment: You can also use a couple of layers of cheesecloth. But pre-filtering first (e. g. with a fine sieve or even a mesh jelly bag) is a very good idea as it clogs easily.